# External Systems Integration Best Practice

Tags: java, architecture, integration

Quick question on what is the best practice for integrating with external systems.

We have a system that deals with Companies which we represent by our own objects. We also use an external system via SOAP that returns a Organization object. They are very similar but not the same (ours is a subset of theirs).

My question is, should we wrap the SOAP service via a Facade so we return only Company objects to our application, or should we return another type of object (e.g. OrgCompany), or even just use the Organization object in our code.

The SOAP service and Organization object are defined by an external company (a bank), who we have no control over.

Any advice and justification is much appreciated.

Comment: I would check these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus and http://www.mulesoft.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decision here is how you want to manage external code dependencies in your application. Some factors that should play into your decision:
1) How often will the API change, and what's the expected nature of the changes?
2) What's the utility of your application outside its depdencies? If you removed the SOAP service dependency, would your app still serve a purpose?

A defensive approach is to build a facade or adapter around SOAP service, so that your code only depends on your object model. This gives you a lot of control and a relatively loose coupling between your code/logic and the service. The price that you pay for this control is that when the SOAP contract changes, you must also usually also change a layer of your code.

A different approach is to use the objects you're getting from the WSDL directly. This is beneficial when it doesn't make sense to introduce a level of indirection in your application between the client code, i.e. your application is just a feeder into a different system and the whole point of the app is to stuff the Organization object into a JMS pipeline or something similar. If the SOAP API contract never changes and you don't expect the output of your app to change much, then introducing an extra layer of indirection will just hinder the readability of your codebase long term.

Most j2ee developers tend to take the former approach in my experience, both because of the nature of their applications, and wanting to separate their application logic from the details of the data source.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

My two cents, Introducing external objects into application is always a problem. Especially during maintenance. A small service change might lead into big code change in the application.

It's always good to have a layer abstraction between the external service and application. I would suggest to create a service layer which will do the translation of external service object to your application domain objects and use them within the application. A clear separation / decoupling helps a lot in maintenance.

The below diagram depicts the above content.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any situation where it's good to use the objects that another company controls. The first thing you should do is bridge those objects into your own. Also, by having your own objects, you can expand their functionality beyond the one that is provided by the third party you connect to (for example if in the future you need to talk to more than one Company object provider)

Look at the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

I'd support Sridhars suggestion, I'd like just to add that for translating external service objects to your application domain you can use Dozer :

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. I really appreciate it. I selected Paul's answer as the most preferable only because it was the most comprehensive. But I thing everyone is unanimous on this issue. Thanks again. Adam

Answer (score 0):

I typically always [Adapt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) externally defined domain objects to an internal representation.

I also create a comprehensive suite of tests against the external domain object, that will highlight any problems quickly if the external vendor produces a new release.

Answer (score 0):

The [Enterprise service bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) Architecture might be useful here

> Its primary use is in Enterprise Application Integration of
>   heterogeneous and complex landscapes.

(from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus))

I would check out open source [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/) if you are looking for an open source solution